# GraalVM JavaScript in Java - How to identify an async method

Tags: javascript, java, promise, graalvm, polyglot

Consider we have the following JS code:

```
    async function helloAsync(){
        return "Hello";
    }

    function hello(){
        return "Hello";
    }
```

In Java, you can load this code into a GraalVM context object using:

```
    context.eval("js", mappingTemplate);
```

Giving us two members that we can evaluate using:

```
    Value bindings = context.getBindings("js");
    final Value executionResult1 = bindings.getMember("hello")
                        .execute();
    final Value executionResult2 = bindings.getMember("helloAsync")
                        .execute();
```

As a result, the `executionResult2` would be a promise that can be completed within Java. My question is how I can reliably tell that `executionResult2` is in fact a promise, and not just a string like `executionResult1`. Currently, a naive and unreliable approach could be:

```
if (executionResult.toString().startsWith("Promise") &&
                    executionResult.hasMember("then") && executionResult.hasMember("catch"))
```

What are more reliable/elegant ways of recognizing a promise returned from JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to inspect the content via [this](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/Value.html#getMetaObject--) `value.getMetaObject()`.

The doc say:

> Returns the metaobject that is associated with this value or null if
> no metaobject is available. The metaobject represents a description of
> the object, reveals it's kind and it's features. Some information that
> a metaobject might define includes the base object's type, interface,
> class, methods, attributes, etc.

Could be useful for your case.

Comment: This certainly does sound like a better idea. Like checking if `value.getMetaObject().getMetaSimpleName().equals("Promise")`. I will mark this as answer if I don't find a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `value.getMetaObject()` is the way to go: it returns the JS constructor associated with the `value` instance, which should be `Promise` in your case.